# Скрипт действие курсора за рамками окна браузера

Tags: javascript

Можно как то координаты курсора вверх сместить на срабатывание в пределах 1 см от верхнего края браузера к примеру? То есть за рамками рабочей области.

Просто скрипт срабатывает на открытие поп ап окна при выходе с сайта, но неудобно, так как окно появляется просто если мышка в браузерной строке находится или в закладках. А надо что бы только если к вкладкам подводится.

Вот пример страницы:

````
  <head>
<script src="/js/libs/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="module">

// функция возвращает cookie с именем name, если есть, если нет, то undefined    
function getCookie(name) {
    var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
    "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
    ));
    return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
}
// проверяем, есть ли у нас cookie, с которой мы не показываем окно и если нет, запускаем показ
var alertwin = getCookie("alertwin");
if (alertwin != "no") { 
    $(document).mouseleave(function(e){
        if (e.clientY < 0) {
            $(".exitblock").fadeIn("fast");    
            // записываем cookie на 1 день, с которой мы не показываем окно
            var date = new Date;
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);    
            document.cookie = "alertwin=no; path=/; expires=" + date.toUTCString();       
        }    
    });
    $(document).click(function(e) {
        if (($(".exitblock").is(':visible')) && (!$(e.target).closest(".exitblock .modaltext").length)) {
            $(".exitblock").remove();
        }
    });  
}
$(document).mouseleave(function(e){
    if (e.pageY < 0) {
        $(".exitblock").fadeIn("fast");
    }    
});
isMobile = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|Android|BlackBerry|iPad|IEMobile|Opera Mini)/);
if (isMobile) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        // Копируем сюда
    }, 30000);  
}
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (($(".exitblock").is(':visible')) && (!$(e.target).closest(".exitblock .modaltext").length)) {
        $(".exitblock").remove();
    }
});
  </script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css"/>
  <style>
  @media (min-width: 576px){
.modal-dialog_1 {
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px -2px #444;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    max-width: 650px;
    margin: 1.75rem auto;
    min-height: 300px;
    height: 400px !important;
    
}
}

.modal-header_1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 2rem 1rem;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #dee2e6;
}
  .exitblock {    
      background: #2e262d;
    display:none;    
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:100000;
}    

.modal-content_1 {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    pointer-events: auto;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 0px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2) !important;
    border-radius: 0rem !important;
    outline: 0;
    background-image: url(https://itmlab.ru/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/caa44463bac0ceaf3e5b5a1a227cdce6.gif);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 400px !important;
}

/* EFFECT SLIDE RIGHT CSS*/
#myModal--slideSpeedRight.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
   transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0) skewX(-30deg);
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
   transition: all 0.3s;
}

#myModal--slideSpeedRight.modal.fade.in .modal-dialog {
   animation: slideSpeedRight ease-out 0.5s;
   animation-iteration-count: 1;
   transform-origin: 50% 50%;
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   /*when the spec is finished*/
   -webkit-animation: slideSpeedRight ease-out 0.5s;
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
   -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
   -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   /*Chrome 16+, Safari 4+*/
   -moz-animation: slideSpeedRight ease-out 0.5s;
   -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
   -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
   -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   /*FF 5+*/
   -o-animation: slideSpeedRight ease-out 0.5s;
   -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
   -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
   -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   /*Not implemented yet*/
   -ms-animation: slideSpeedRight ease-out 0.5s;
   -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
   -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
   -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   /*IE 10+*/
}
.modal-content_1 {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    pointer-events: auto;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
    outline: 0;
}
@keyframes slideSpeedRight {
   0% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translate(300px, 0px) skewX(-30deg);
   }
   60% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translate(-40px, 0px) skewX(30deg);
   }
   80% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translate(0px, 0px) skewX(-15deg);
   }
   100% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translate(0px, 0px) skewX(0deg);
   }
}

@-moz-keyframes slideSpeedRight {
   0% {
      opacity: 0;
      -moz-transform: translate(300px, 0px) skewX(-30deg);
   }
   60% {
      opacity: 1;
      -moz-transform: translate(-40px, 0px) skewX(30deg);
   }
   80% {
      opacity: 1;
      -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px) skewX(-15deg);
   }
   100% {
      opacity: 1;
      -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px) skewX(0deg);
   }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideSpeedRight {
   0% {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translate(300px, 0px) skewX(-30deg);
   }
   60% {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-40px, 0px) skewX(30deg);
   }
   80% {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) skewX(-15deg);
   }
   100% {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) skewX(0deg);
   }
}

@-o-keyframes slideSpeedRight {
   0% {
      opacity: 0;
      -o-transform: translate(300px, 0px) skewX(-30deg);
   }
   60% {
      opacity: 1;
      -o-transform: translate(-40px, 0px) skewX(30deg);
   }
   80% {
      opacity: 1;
      -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px) skewX(-15deg);
   }
   100% {
      opacity: 1;
      -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px) skewX(0deg);
   }
}

@-ms-keyframes slideSpeedRight {
   0% {
      opacity: 0;
      -ms-transform: translate(300px, 0px) skewX(-30deg);
   }
   60% {
      opacity: 1;
      -ms-transform: translate(-40px, 0px) skewX(30deg);
   }
   80% {
      opacity: 1;
      -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px) skewX(-15deg);
   }
   100% {
      opacity: 1;
      -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px) skewX(0deg);
   }
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex; /* flex || inline-flex */
}
.flex-container-1, .flex-container-2 {
width:50%;
}
.elementor-heading-title {
    color: #2f2f2f !important;
    font-family: "Bebas Neue", Sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.razmer_0 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
.razmer_1 {
font-size: 40px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
.razmer_2 {
    font-size: 75px;
    }
</style>
  <body>
        


 <div class="modal  exitblock" id="myModal--slideLeft" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog_1 modal-dialog" role="document">
         <div class="modal-content_1">
            <div class="modal-header_1">
       <a href="#" class="popup_1_close" data-hide-overflow=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-container-1"><img width="100%" height="auto" src="https://itmlab.ru/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/314a2856c47596b485162f23aa3b297a.png" class="attachment-large size-large" alt="" decoding="async" loading="lazy" srcset="https://itmlab.ru/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/314a2856c47596b485162f23aa3b297a.png 564w, https://itmlab.ru/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/314a2856c47596b485162f23aa3b297a-300x300.png 300w, https://itmlab.ru/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/314a2856c47596b485162f23aa3b297a-150x150.png 150w" sizes="(max-width: 564px) 100vw, 564px"></div>
  <div class="flex-container-2">
  <div class="elementor-heading-title razmer_0">Уже уходите?</div>
  <div class="elementor-heading-title razmer_1">лучше воспользуйтесь нашим промокодом на скидку</div>
  <div class="elementor-heading-title razmer_2">poster10</div>
  </div>
</div>
    
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Вы не можете отслеживать положение курсора за пределами самой страницы.

Comment: Для ваших целей можно отслеживать попытку закрытия вкладки - событие window.onbeforeunload.